# cant build project ERROR: 'FetchXmlHttpFactory' is not exported from '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

I am trying to build my project but I am getting error:
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/prebuilt-db9cc925-eb007c37.js
> Attempted import error: 'FetchXmlHttpFactory' is not exported from
> '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper' (imported as 'v').
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! test-admin@0.1.0
> build: `react-scripts build` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the test-admin@0.1.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably
> not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> above.

I tried to install latest firebase but no luck. This is My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^2.3.3",
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper": "0.4.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^8.6.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^3.14.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-admin": "^3.14.2",
    "react-admin-firebase": "^3.2.17",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

And this is my firebase config file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
export const config = {
  apiKey: *******,
  authDomain: *******,
  databaseURL: *******,
  projectId: *******,
  storageBucket: *******,
  messagingSenderId:*******,
  appId: *******,
  measurementId: *******,
};

export const options = {
  logging: false,
  rootRef: "root_collection/some_document",
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
const db = firebase.firestore();
export default db;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue earlier. This is how I resolved it.
If you have firebase version: 8.6.4, uninstall using `npm uninstall firebase`. Then reinstall using `npm install firebase@8.6.3`